# Creating Testdata in HTML format for Robot test framework in python

Tags: unit-testing, python-2.7, testcase, robotframework, test-framework

I am trying to use robot test framework. I have some knowledge in python. I read most of the tutorials available online but all the tutorials are explaining some example but when it comes to my work(I have to use keyword or data driven testing) i am not able to sync to tutorial examples. Can some one suggest me how to start working with robot framework.
RIDE IDE tutorial is also explaining some quick start example but not clear(may be to me).

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear, but the title says you're trying to create test data (actual test data, or test cases?) in HTML. Here's an example of a test case written in the HTML format:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Example test suite</h1>

    <p>This is an example of a test suite written in HTML format </p>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Test Cases</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Example test case</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td><td>Log</td><td>Hello, world</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```